# Change just 1 key in a serialised array with 3 keys using php function

Tags: php, arrays, serialization, woocommerce, wpallimport

I am trying to import values which are stored as a serialised array with 3 keys like this:

```
a:3:{i:754;s:0:"";i:753;s:0:"";i:752;s:0:"";}
```

Would anyone know a php function to change the value within 1 key (adjust 754) and leave the other keys as they were?

I'm using WP ALL Import and i can match my records and adjust the value for 754, but it changes the entire serialised array, deleting the other values in the other 2 keys

Thank you in advance

Comment: Unserialize the array and change the key as one usually would? How exactly are you trying to adjust the value?

Comment: Not clear! Do you want to adjust the Key (754) or the value which is currently `""`

Comment: Apologies, it was to replace the value within "" inside key 745 - Thank you @MarkusAO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would replace the value of array Occurance 754

```
$serial = 'a:3:{i:754;s:0:"";i:753;s:0:"";i:752;s:0:"";}';

$arr = unserialize($serial);

$arr[754] = 'NEW';
print_r($arr);
echo $serial = serialize($arr);
```

RESULT

```
Array
(
    [754] => NEW
    [753] => 
    [752] => 
)
a:3:{i:754;s:3:"NEW";i:753;s:0:"";i:752;s:0:"";}
```